# Как заставить картинки обрезаться средствами css?

Tags: html, css, css3, bootstrap

Как заставить изображения в сетке ботстрап бфть квадратными(одинаковыми), чтобы получилась нормальная галлерея с квадратиками.(может плохо выражаюсь)
Зайдите на http://new.4host.xyz/pages/blank.html и все поймете.

Comment: "Зайдите на *** и все поймете." - зашел и ничего не понял. Приложите скриншот к вопросу и опишите ожидаемое поведение.

Comment: Все просто, первые 2 картинки видите, третья должна быть такого же размера средствами css. то есть должен на такой " не влезающей картинке" блок быть размером как и везде, но не ужиматься, а показываться только середина.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```css
.b-pict {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px auto;     
}
.b-pict > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .b-pict {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 170px;
  }
  .b-pict > img {
    max-width: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://new.4host.xyz/img/1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://new.4host.xyz/img/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://new.4host.xyz/img/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://new.4host.xyz/img/4.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://new.4host.xyz/img/5.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
      <div class="b-pict">
        <img src="http://new.4host.xyz/img/6.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все бы ничего, но тогда нормальные картинки начинают выглядеть ппц как

Comment: хороший пример , 10 от меня